# Error while running Spring Boot application - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, oauth-2.0

I am creating a simple Rest service using Spring Boot and later I will add OAuth2 security in it. My pom.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringSecurityDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>SpringSecurityDemo</name>
    <description>SpringBootDemo2</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Besides that I have created one simple RestController

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/sayHello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

When  am trying to run this my program with these class and pom, I am getting the following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) [spring-boot-test-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint(ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.java:50) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10295013.CGLIB$configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10295013$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8a7239b6.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10295013.configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 57 common frames omitted

2019-03-01 23:26:17.900 ERROR 3116 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@198f307] to prepare test instance [com.example.demo.SpringSecurityDemoApplicationTests@1cc680e]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint(ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.java:50) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10295013.CGLIB$configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10295013$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8a7239b6.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10295013.configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 57 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.502 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.demo.SpringSecurityDemoApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.example.demo.SpringSecurityDemoApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint]: Factory method 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   SpringSecurityDemoApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.649 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-01T23:26:18+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/50M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone please say me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe you need a dependency on jackson-databind. e.g. In pom.xml add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```